# Multiple Grails projects named the same Build problems

Tags: grails, setup-project, dependency-management

I currently have one workspace for our 'Mainline' code, and 1 workspace for each branch that we create at the end of each iteration.  I am using STS and grails 1.3.6, with no added plugins and a couple of java jar files.  It seems like whenever I create a new workspace for a new branch, the branch workspace ends up getting corrupted.  I start getting build errors locally revolving around missing hibernate classes such as `AbstractEntityPersister`.  I am working in a Windows 7 environment.

My question is two-fold.

One-Is this problem likely related to a caching issue?  Theoretically the build grails dependency jars should be the same between the workspaces, so I don't know why one workspace would have problems and one wouldn't

Two-What is the best way to debug said problem?  Currently the only thing I'm going on is the Problems view and then comparing the two workspaces as best I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, grails uses "$USER_HOME/.grails/grailsVersion/projectName" as a working directory, so having two projects with the same name and same grails version will cause you several headaches.

Take a look at the docs below, you'll want to set 'projectWorkDir' in each project BuildConfig to prevent interferences.

http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#buildCustomising

Answer (score 1):

Do your project working directories have the exact same name?

Grails creates a project cache folder in `$USER_HOME/.grails/<grailsVersion>/projects/<basedirname>` which contains compiled plugins and scripts. Even running `grails clean` does not wipe out these directories.

It's likely that the two projects that have the same name are updating files in this folder simultaneously. In theory this shouldn't mess anything up because you're probably not working on the two projects simultaneously, but if you have both open in STS it might be auto building and messing with the automatic reloading mechanism that Grails uses.

I would try to set the working directory in `BuildConfig.groovy` or override the folder using `grails -Dgrails.project.work.dir=work` [as documented](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#buildCustomising).

Failing this, I would suggest disabling any auto build in STS as Grails itself will compile/reload classes when `run-app` is running. Also I would try editing your application using a text editor (Sublime Text 2 is fantastic) instead of STS to see if you have the same problems.